# How do I create a 10x10 addition table using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need a hand with this project I am working on, I cant seem to find out why my code isn't working. My goal is to display a addition table similar to this one:

[image]

My code for this table so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
?>
<?php echo "<table border=\"1\">";

<?php echo "<table>";
for($a = 1; $a < $rows;$a++)

echo'<tr>';

for($b = 1;$b < $cols; $b++);
echo '<td>'($answer = $a + $b); '</td>'

  echo"</table>";
  ?>
  <br>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Is this your real code? It contains several basic syntax errors. Please, make sure you copy and paste your code, don't re-type it into here, as it has the potential to introduce silly problems, which then distract us from your actual issue. If this _is_ your real code, then please fix all the silly syntax errors and then come back if you have a more useful question. You didn't actually explain to us what specific problem you're having - "isn't working" tell us nothing. Do you get an error message, or unexpected output, or what?

Comment: P.S. It's also going to produce completely invalid HTML, even when you fix the basics.

Comment: Please see my latest version.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of typos and omissions. The worst are the missing or extraneous semicolons

Here is working code using array notation
https://onlinephp.io/c/a97d8

```
<?php
$cols = 10;
$rows = 12; 
$table[]="<table><tbody><tr><td>+</td>";
for($a = 1; $a < $rows;$a++) { 
  $table[] = "<td>$a</td>";
  for($b = 1;$b < $cols; $b++) $table[]= "<td>".($answer = $a + $b)."</td>";
  if ($a<$rows-1) {
    $table[] = "</tr>";
    $table[] = "<tr><td>$a</td>";
  }
} 
$table[] = "</tr></tbody></table>";
echo implode($table);
?>
```

Output

Note the CSS  - it is quite complex

`table tr:nth-of-type(2n+3)` : stripe from 3rd row

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 2em;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  background-color: pink;
  color: black;
}

table tr:first-child>td:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2n+3)  {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>+</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is with PHP and CSS Grid:

https://paiza.io/projects/oHTe6JJGbeXX85Hij6X0VQ?language=php

```
<div class="table">
<?php
    $rows = 10;
    $cols = 10;

    for($i=0; $i<$rows+1; $i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j<$cols+1; $j++)
        {
            echo "<div>";
            echo $i == 0 && $j == 0 ? "+" : $i + $j;
            echo "</div>";    
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Result:

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
}

.table > div {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
} 

.table > div:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
}

.table > div:nth-child(11n + 12) {
  background-color: pink;
}

.table > div:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+11) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div>+</div><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>17</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>17</div><div>18</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>17</div><div>18</div><div>19</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>17</div><div>18</div><div>19</div><div>20</div></div>
```